# Add custom fields upon user creation

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to add custom fields using the hooks:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

and it perfectly fine but it only shows upon editing of users and not upon creating new users. How can I add custom fields upon creation? Can I also specify to only show this field depending on the selected user role?

**Edit**

[image: function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {]

Also tried the suggestion:

```
do_action( 'user_new_form', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom fields using follows- hook to show it in add user section.

```
do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-new-user' );
```

And the code snippet are as follows -

```
// Add extra custom data
function extra_user_profile_fields(){
    ?>
    <h3>Extra User Profile data</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="company">Company Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="company_name" value="" id="company_name" /><br />
                <span class="description">Add your company name.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
add_action( "user_new_form", "extra_user_profile_fields" );

// Used to save extra custom data
function save_extra_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    if(isset($_POST['company_name']))
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_user_company', $_POST['company_name']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields');
```

And you can show or hide this fields for selected user role using scripts.

Comment: Can I also adjust this to that it would only show to certain user role?

Comment: @Bon Andre Opina, yes you can.

Comment: Ill add a photo in my comment

Comment: @BonAndreOpina I updated code snippet to add fields on add new user section.

Comment: Thanks about that will try this and will see what it does.. BTW what do you mean by scripts? Is it jquery where I bind the user select button?